# Unable to remove my extension from vs2017

Tags: visual-studio-2017, uninstallation, visual-studio-extensions

I am trying to create a vs2017 extension, after writing some code I installed it to test and it didn't work, then I fixed the code and tried to install again and it says extension already installed. How many times I uninstall it from vs2017 it just gets disabled but not removed. Please help to uninstall. Even I have tried to uninstall from command line but no luck.

Comment: try to set .NET Framework 4.5.2 or below 4.6.

Comment: @AsifAli72090 where ? My extension project ? But my problem is to remove the old extension from vs2017

Comment: @Krishna, Do you remove it from the Extensions and Updates window in VS IDE or others? Do you restart your VS or restart your machine after you remove or uninstall it? Please also try to delete it from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\Extensions, of course, please update your VS to the latest version, test the result again.

Comment: @JackZhai-MSFT yes removed from extension window. Restarted vs nothing worked. Will try folder removal

Comment: @Krishna, What about this issue? Could you remove it from the Extensions folder after you uninstall it or disable it? Please also try to clean up the temp files in your side.

Comment: @JackZhai-MSFT I didn’t get chance yesterday will try today and will let you know

Comment: @JackZhai-MSFT i don't see it in that folder

Comment: @JackZhai-MSFT I found in another thread that I need to remove it from user app data, I found it there and removed. But in future when I give this people I can’t expect them to delete from appdata right is there any installer I need to use for this ?

Comment: @Krishna, Do you mean that it works well now? Is it like this report here?https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/31263/vs2017-fails-to-start-with-unknown-error.html. What is your windows Environment? What is your VS2017 version number,15.3 Preview or others?

Comment: @JackZhai-MSFT I am not getting any errors when opening the vs2017, but I am unable to uninstall my extension frin "extensions & Updates" window. When ever I try to uninstall it just disables it. I want to provide users with a clean uninstall option. I am working on windows 7 enterprise, vs2017 professional edition

Comment: @Krishna, I couldn't repro this issue in my side, just to make this issue clearly, do you run your VS as the admin during you remove/disable the extension? Whether there are other admin users in your machine? One possible workaround is that whether we could use certain script to clean up the user files automatically before we re-install the extension again in our side.